# recv in TCP implementation in C is not always working as expected

Tags: c, server, tcp, network-programming, client

I need to write an implementation of the TCP protocol in C between a client and a server, where the client specifies how many messages are to be sent and the length of them (the message itself is just an int). The server receives the messages and prints them in hex format. What I need to do is that instead of TCP just printing a bunch of messages as they are received, wait for the whole content to be together and then print it.

For example, te client sends:

Number of messages: 4
Lenght: 6

So the server should print:
RECV_NO: 0, Length: 24, Content: 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x2, 0x2, 0x2, 0x2, 0x2, 0x2, 0x3, 0x3, 0x3, 0x3, 0x3, 0x3

Instead of for example:
RECV_NO: 0, Length: 20, Content: 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x2, 0x2, 0x2, 0x2, 0x2, 0x2, 0x3, 0x3
RECV_NO: 1, Length: 4, Content: 0x3, 0x3, 0x3, 0x3

The problem is that for long messages, the recv function receives the message as a negative number and I don't know why this is happening.

Here is the code:

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

unsigned int addHeader(int x, int y) {
    int pow = 10;
    while(y >= pow)
        pow *= 10;
    return x * pow + y;        
}

int sendx(int sock, int num, int len, int par) {
    char message[10000];
    unsigned int newTcp = addHeader(par, num);
    memset(message, newTcp, len);
    return send(sock, &message, len, 0);
}

int main() {
    struct sockaddr_in myaddr;
    myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myaddr.sin_port = htons(50000);
    myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    
    int socketId = -1, sockConnect = -1, sockSend = -1;
    int sendLen = 0, count = 0;
    
    socketId = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socketId < 0) {
        printf("socket creation failed");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Socket is created.\n");
    
    sockConnect = connect(socketId, (struct sockaddr*) &myaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
     if(sockConnect < 0) {
        printf("connect failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Sucessfully conected with server.\n");
    
    while(1) {
        int sendNo = 0;
        printf("Enter the number of messages to be sent: ");
        scanf("%d", &count);
        printf("Enter the length: ");
        scanf("%d", &sendLen);
        int total = count*sendLen;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            sockSend = sendx(socketId, sendNo, sendLen, total);
            if(sockSend < 0) {
                printf("send failed");
                return 1;
            }
            sendNo++;
        }
    }
    
    close(socketId);
    return 0;
}
```

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAXBUF 64000

char totalMsg[MAXBUF];

int recvx(int accept, char *msg, int buf, int par) {
    totalMsg[0] = '\0';
    char* p = totalMsg;
    char str[12];
    
    size_t recvd = -1;
    recvd = recv(accept, msg, buf, par);    
    int head = msg[0]/10;
    ssize_t bytesRemaining = head - recvd;

    if(bytesRemaining == 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < recvd; i++) {
            sprintf(str, "0x%X ", msg[i] % 10);
            strcat(totalMsg, str);
        }
    } else {
        while(bytesRemaining > 0) {
            recvd = recv(accept, msg, buf, par);
            printf("recvd in while: %ld\n", recvd);
            for(int i = 0; i < recvd; i++) {
                printf("msg[i]: %d\n", msg[i]);
                sprintf(str, "0x%X ", msg[i] % 10);
                strcat(totalMsg, str);
            }
            bytesRemaining -= recvd;     // keep track of bytes left
            p += recvd;                  // advance buffer pointer
        }
    }
    
    return recvd;
}
 

int main() {
    struct sockaddr_in myaddr;
    myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myaddr.sin_port = htons(50000);
    myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    
    int socketId = -1, recvLen = -1;
    int sockBind = -1, sockListen = -1, sockAccept = -1, recvNo = 0;
    
    socketId = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socketId < 0) {
        printf("socket creation failed");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Socket created.\n");
    
    sockBind = bind(socketId, (struct sockaddr*) &myaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
     if(sockBind < 0) {
        perror("bind failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Successful bind.\n");
    
    sockListen = listen(socketId, 5);
    if(sockListen < 0) {
        printf("listen failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Waiting for incoming connections...\n");
    
    unsigned int srcAddrLen = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    sockAccept = accept(socketId, (struct sockaddr*) &myaddr, &srcAddrLen);
    if (sockAccept < 0) {
        perror("accept failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Connection accepted.\n");
    
    while(1) {
        char client_message[MAXBUF];
        memset(client_message, '0', MAXBUF);
        
        recvLen = recvx(sockAccept, client_message, MAXBUF, 0);
        if(recvLen < 0) { 
            printf("recv failed\n");
            break;
        } else if(recvLen == 0) {
            printf("connection lost\n");
            break;
        }
        
        printf("RECV_NO: %d, Laenge: %d, Inhalt: %s\n\n", recvNo, recvLen, totalMsg);
        recvNo++;
    }
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

My idea was to add somthng like an 'extra header' with the total number of messages the server would have to join, but I found that when there are mode than 10 or so messages, the recv function puts negative numbers in what should be the message from the client and it just breaks, but I don't know how to solve this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What you are describing is not TCP but a different protocol. TCP is _not_ a message-based protocol, it is a stream protocol. Application-layer protocols that run on TCP can be message protocols, e.g. HTTP. You would be better off creating an application-layer-protocol that runs on top of TCP.

Comment: Yeah, this is totally borked because you do not understand TCP:(

Comment: 'recv in TCP implementation in C is not always working as expected' - read the RFC and revise your expectations:)

Comment: *>implementation of the TCP protocol*  Your description is inaccurate. Your code is not an implementation of TCP protocol but implementation of custom application-layer protocol on top of TCP.

Comment: The title of your post should be your specific question to get more attention.